# Iterating over an object of type Iterator<T>

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

While reading through the Wikipedia article on  [`Generators`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29#Java), I found the following Java implementation to iterate over a generic type `Iterator<Integer>` produce an infinite sequence of Fibonacci numbers

```
Iterator<Integer> fibo = new Iterator<Integer>() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int total;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        total = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = total;
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
// this could then be used as...
for(int f: fibo) {
    System.out.println("next Fibonacci number is " + f);
    if (someCondition(f)) break;
}
```

However, the above code does't work when put inside `main` method of a class. It says

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

which is understandable. Does it mean the above example is wrong or incomplete? Am I missing something?

Comment: An `Iterator` is not an `Iterable`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, I know that but I am asking about the code snippet on the Wikipedia page. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: @ajay something like:  `while(hasNext() ) {   next()  }`

Comment: It's not. That won't compile. Whoever wrote it made a mistake.

Comment: Don't take `Wikipedia` as an authorative source.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There's another similar code snippet above the example I quoted here. I got concerned as to how Wikipedia can be so misleading. In case I missed something, I asked here to clarify.

Comment: @gtgaxiola True but being wrong and misleading is dangerous given that Wikipedia is so popular. Someone's got to correct it.

Comment: Fixed the examples on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code sample on Wikipedia is invalid, but you can easily iterate anyway, just by calling `hasNext()` and `next()` explicitly.

```
// We know that fibo.hasNext() will always return true, but
// in general you don't...
while (fibo.hasNext()) {
    int f = fibo.next();
    System.out.println("next Fibonacci number is " + f);
    if (someCondition(f)) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove for loop and use while loop. As iterator is not array type or collection.
Try this

```
while(fibo.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(fibo.next());
```

}